# Apply method of DataFrame vs List Comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the list of some specific indexes of a pandas Series; and the list of all these lists for all the Series of a DataFrame.

I can do it with list comprehension but I would like to understand if I can do that with the apply method of DataFrame. Here is a toy model:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,0,1,0,0,1]})
[a[a[name]==1].index for name in a.columns]
```

Probably it is just because of my shallow knowledge of pandas, but when I use the apply method   I imagine the serie as a list or so end hence I do not have any idea on how to "put" the index attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your end goal is, but often better to keep a frame as a frame for future operations.

```
In [1]:  a=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,0,0,1],'b':[1,0,1,0,0,1]})
```

Convert the elements you are not interested in to nan

```
In [2]: a.where(a==1)
Out[2]: 
    a   b
0   1   1
1   1 NaN
2   1   1
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
5   1   1

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

If you really want the index

```
In [4]: a.where(a==1)['a'].dropna().index
Out[4]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 5], dtype='int64')

In [5]: a.where(a==1)['b'].dropna().index
Out[5]: Int64Index([0, 2, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: The end goal is to sum together consecutive ones, and I know how to do that using their indexes: so the end result will be [[3,1],[1,1,1]]. I see that the way you get the indexes it is pretty different, maybe performs better, but you are still calling the series one by one and it will result in a list comprehension over a.columns. Isn't it?

Comment: If you want to create a list comprehension in the end, then yes you need to iterate.